# Set default program to open special file extension in vs.net

Tags: c#, visual-studio, templates

I want to set special program to open my template item in visual studio and deploying this to other VS.net.
when you add new crystal report in your project it open with crystal report editor by default (right-click on rpt file and select open with option)
I want to set my program to open file with special extension in vs.net (my extension is filename.xr )
please advise me about a way to deploying it and also it must open integrated not as third party program.

Comment: Re comment about **deploying** this to other VS; I suggest you edit the question to include this important detail ;-p

Answer (score 1):

In the "Open With..." dialog, use "Add..." to select your editor / tool, then click "Set as Default".

Note that I'm assuming this is for your personal use, and not as part of a VS customisation to deploy.

Comment: I knew it and need to find a way for deploy it